# Average performance measurements for local IPC

Tags: performance, sockets, tcp, ipc, rpc

We are now assessing different IPC (or rather RPC) methods for our current project, which is in its very early stages. Performance is a big deal, and so we are making some measurements to aid our choice. Our processes that will be communicating will reside **on the same machine**.

A separate valid option is to avoid IPC altogether (by encapsulating the features of one of the processes in a .NET DLL and having the other one use it), but this is an option we would really like to avoid, as these two pieces of software are developed by two separate companies and we find it very important to maintain good "fences", which make good neighbors.

Our tests consisted of passing messages (which contain variously sized BLOBs) across process boundaries using each method. These are the figures we get (performance range correlates with message size range):

- Web Service (SOAP over HTTP):

  - **25-30 MB/s** when binary data is encoded as Base64 (default)
  - **70-100 MB/s** when MTOM is utilized
- .NET Remoting (BinaryFormatter over TCP): **100-115 MB/s**
- Control group - DLL method call + mem copy: **800-1000 MB/s**

Now, we've been looking all over the place for some average performance figures for these (and other) IPC methods, including performance of raw TCP loopback sockets, but couldn't find any. Do these figures look sane? Why is the performance of these local IPC methods at least 10 times slower than copying memory? I couldn't get better results even when I used raw sockets - is the overhead of TCP that big?

Comment: @user289770, I suppose you have pretty large payloads, otherwise you would be interested in latency too.

Comment: @user289770, Have you measured transfer rate including protocol overhead or just the payload? Have you estimated how much overhead you have?

Comment: @Albin, yes, many of my messages have rather large payloads (could be as much as 30 MB). The rest will be several KBs. I have measured transfer rate including the protocol overhead - that's the whole point.

Comment: Sorry, I may have misunderstood the question: the size in MBs refers to payload only. The time measured includes everything, including any overhead.

Comment: Can you try remoting over udp for comparison?

Comment: Also try IPC as the transport under Remoting.

Comment: @dss539: when messages are big (>3 MB), IpcChannel performs rather poorly compared to the TcpChannel. For smaller messages IPC performs slightly better, but unfortunately I need to transfer messages as big as 30 MB.

Comment: Also, I'm not aware of a UDP channel for Remoting (at least not as part of the framework), but wouldn't it be far less reliable?

Comment: How do you lose packets on an imaginary wire? You said this was all on the same machine, right? Re: Support - Maybe UDP support isn't included with Remoting. I thought it was. Also, I'm a little surprised that TCP beats IPC. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Surely there will be no loss with UDP on the local machine (it's in the programmer's bill of rights to assume RAM and TCP do not err).

Comment: Now to the real question: Are fancy IPC techniques just not good enough and people should use shared memory above certain performance? At which bandwidth does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Several parts of our system have been redesigned so that we don't have to pass 30MB messages around, but rather 3MB. This allowed us to choose .NET Remoting with BinaryFormatter over named pipes (IpcChannel), which gives satisfactory results.
- Our contingency plan (in case we ever do need to pass 30MB messages around) is to pass protobuf-serialized messages over named pipes manually. We have determined that this also provides satisfactory results.

Answer (score 3):

Shared memory is the fastest.

A producer process can put its output into memory shared between processes and notify other processes that the shared data has been updated. On Linux you naturally put a mutex and a condition variable in that same shared memory so that other processes can wait for updates on the condition variable.

Answer (score 0):

Memory-mapped files + synchronization objects is the right way to go (almost the same as shared memory, but with more control). Sockets are way too slow for local communications. Especially it sometimes happens that network drivers are slower with localhost, than over network.